# Simd not on my Linux machine: fatal error: simd/simd.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, macos, simd

I have a codebase that I can compile and run on my Mac but not on my remote Linux box and I am not sure why.

When I compile I get the error:

```
fatal error: simd/simd.h: No such file or directory
```

I am running the command:

```bash
g++ -std=c++11 -c Tester.cpp
```

I have been trying install simd but I cant find instructions for that anywhere. I must not be looking in the right place? Is it possible simd is just not available on my Linux machine?

Comment: What functions are you expecting to find in it?  `#include <immintrin.h>` for Intel's x86 SIMD intriniscs.  https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/.  (And see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info)

Answer (score 1):

`simd/simd.h` is an [Apple simd](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd?language=objc) header that can only be used on Apple platforms.

However, upon further investigation, the types defined in `simd.h` (more specifically its sub-headers [`simd/vector_types.h`](https://github.com/mstg/iOS-full-sdk/blob/master/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/usr/include/simd/vector_types.h) and [`simd/matrix_types.h`](https://github.com/mstg/iOS-full-sdk/blob/master/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/usr/include/simd/matrix_types.h)) simply seem to define the SIMD types as aliases to [GCC vector extensions types](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html).

Since `<simd/simd.h>` will search for this header inside a system include directory instead of your project directory, if you install a version of `simd/simd.h` that simply contains all the type definitions and function definitions (e.g., `simd_mul`, `matrix_multiply`, etc.), you should be able to compile most if not any code that uses `#include <simd/simd.h>` and the MacOS-style SIMD semantics on any system on which the GCC vectors extension is available.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be some OS X specific header.